# My animation poses aren't showing up in my asset browser

Tags: animation, unreal-4, skeletal-animation

I tried following [this tutorial](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Animation/AnimHowTo/AimOffset/index.html#creatingaimposes()), where they eventually ask me to drag the `Aim_Center` from the asset browser onto the graph. The problem is, the only thing that shows up in my asset browser is the `Aim_Offset` that I created earlier.

Is there something I don't see? This is my first time using animations in the Unreal Engine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to save your asset first.  Make sure your asset uses the same skeleton

Comment: I feel this is a poor question; very simple research would have solved this (I CTRL + F searched for aim_center from your link and there it was), and following the tutorial from the *start* seems to be the solution. I very much doubt this could be of much use to other users; I do not think we close questions for that reason,anymore, so I have provided an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As *Raildex* points out, you need to *create* the asset, first. This is actually stated quite clearly, in the tutorial you have linked.

---

It appears likely that you have mistakenly skipped a part of the tutorial. You mention being told to locate `Aim_Center`, which appears to be [section three](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Animation/AnimHowTo/AimOffset/index.html#implementingtheaimoffset), but only finding `Aim_Offset`, which you would have made in [section two](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Animation/AnimHowTo/AimOffset/index.html#creatingtheaimoffset).

`Aim_Offset` is being made in [section one](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Animation/AnimHowTo/AimOffset/index.html#creatingaimposes). I feel this is *very* clear, though it is referenced as **`Hero_AimOffset`**, *not `Aim_Offset`*. This should not cause any confusion, if you are following the tutorial. This is still consistent with the name used, later, when you are asked to find it.

---

It is important you follow the entire tutorial; *start* to *end*. In this case, the missed section makes up more than the `Hero_AimOffset` asset; it is likely that if you missed *one*, you probably missed *more*.

Comment: I did follow the tutorial from the start, probably copied the wrong link, sorry.Currently, i have https://i.gyazo.com/e23fa39a8d77418918446e065fe934f1.png

Just to be clear: I DID follow the tutorial from the beginning. My fault if it wasn't clear, sorry.